# Moving mixed case folder to all lower case while keeping history

Tags: svn

I'm converting a working copy to all lower case. I have a script that loops and moves a mixed case location to an all lower case location. I'm using `svn move --parent src dst`.

Here is my entire script:

```
IFS=$'\n'
cd /path/to/working/copy

for SRC in `find . -iname '*.*' -depth | grep -v '.svn'`

do
        DST=$(echo "$SRC" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')


        #get directory
        OLD_DIRECTORY="${SRC%/*}"
        NEW_DIRECTORY=$(echo "$OLD_DIRECTORY" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')

        if [ "${SRC}" != "${DST}" ]
        then
                [ ! -e "${DST}" ] && svn move --parents "${SRC}" "${DST}" || echo "${SRC} was not renamed"
        fi
done
```

So far, file history seems to be preserved. However, folder history isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using. This will keep history for files, but not for folders.

```
IFS=$'\n'
cd opensol2

for SRC in `find . -depth -type f | grep -v '.svn'`

do
        NEW_FILE=$(echo "$SRC" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')

        if [ "${SRC}" != "${NEW_FILE}" ]
        then
                [ ! -e "${NEW_FILE}" ] && svn move --parents "${SRC}" "${NEW_FILE}" || echo "${SRC} was not renamed"
        fi
done
```